# NGINX: redirect 301 from url with extension

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm moving from Apache to Nginx and I have to reproduce this old rules.

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This have to permanently redirect (not rewrite) to the same url without the `.html` part.

In NGinx I did this,but it returns a beautiful 404 error:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1 permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was move the rewrite rule in the `server` context and not under the `location`.